# Why authenticate_with_http_token doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, rspec-rails

I have a Users controller that looks like this:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApiController
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods
  before_action :find_user, only: [:show]
  before_action :authenticate, only: [:destroy]

  ...

  def destroy
    if @user
      @user.destroy
    else
      render json: { user: "not found" }, status: :not_found
    end
  end

  private
  
    ...  

    def authenticate
      authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options|
        @user = User.find_by(token: token)
      end
    end
end
```

And I also have this test

```
describe "DELETE #destroy" do
    before(:each) do
      @user = FactoryBot.create :user
      request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = @user.token
      delete :destroy, params: { id: @user.id }
    end

    it { should respond_with 204 }
  end
```

Every time I run `bundle exec rspec` this exact test of destroy method is failing:
[image]
It is happening because of `authenticate_with_http_token` method. I pass the token to HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header, but `authenticate_with_http_token` method doesn't see this token.
I changed the `authenticate` method in the controller to this:

```
def authenticate
  @user = User.find_by(token: request.headers['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])
end
```

And the test is passing fine, everything is working. But I don't really think that taking token out of `request.headers` explicitly is a correct approach and I would like to stick to the `authenticate_with_http_token`. What should I do so `authenticate_with_http_token` will start working properly?

Answer (score 8):

Rails handles tokens from the `Authorization:` header in any of the following formats with the `authenticate_with_http_token` method.

Allowed formats:

```rb
Bearer "your_token"
Bearer your_token
Bearer token="your_token"
Bearer token=your_token
Token token="your_token"
Token token=your_token
Token "your_token"
Token your_token
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
request.headers['Authorization'] = "Token token=xxx"
```

before get, post...

it set into your request header